# How to concatenate a list of sublists equally chunked

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a list that contains sublists of two different types of items (for instance, `cats` and `dogs`). I also have a function `chunk(list, n_sublists)` that splits the `list` into `n_sublists` of equal size.

Then, i'd like to create a final list that merges the chunked lists from each type. An example:

```py
cats_and_dogs = [ [dog1, dog2, dog3, dog4], [cat1, cat2] ]

splitted_chunks = [[[dog1, dog2], 
                    [dog3, dog4]],
                  [[cat1], 
                  [cat2]]] 

final_merged_sublists = [ [dog1, dog2, cat1], [dog3, dog4, cat2] ]
```

I hope the example makes it clear. However, i can provide more explanation if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `splitted_chunks` the output of `chunk(cats_and_dogs, n_sublists=2)`?

Comment: No, I would have to call chunk(dogs, 2) and then chuk(cats) and append both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a loop on zip:

```
list(x+y for x,y in zip(chunk(dogs,2), chunk(cats,2))
```

Output:

```
[['dog1', 'dog2', 'cat1'], ['dog3', 'dog4', 'cat2']]
```

**Update**: in general, use reduce

```
from functools import reduce

splitted_chunks = map(lambda x: chunk(x,2), cats_and_dogs)
list(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, z) for z in zip(*splitted_chunks) )
```

Comment: Good solution. But is it possible to extend this to a more generic case (i.e. list of dogs, cats, zebras, turtles, etc...)

Comment: You don't need `list` for the `map`, keep it as a generator, it will be more efficient.

Comment: @mozway ah, yes. I didn't know we could unpack a generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and `itertools.chain`:

```
splitted_chunks = [[['dog1', 'dog2'], 
                    ['dog3', 'dog4']],
                  [['cat1'], 
                   ['cat2']]] 

from itertools import chain
final_merged_sublists = [list(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in zip(*splitted_chunks)]
```

Output:

```
[['dog1', 'dog2', 'cat1'], ['dog3', 'dog4', 'cat2']]
```

*NB. To apply `chunk` on all sublists of the original list of arbitrary size, use `map`*